# cordova: media.getDuration returns -1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I am using Media.getDuration() function to get duration of an audio file but I am always getting -1 as response.

This works fine if I build using build.phonegap.com

But whenever I build using cli I then getDuration does not work.

Following are simple steps to reproduce this issue:

**CLI:**

```
cordova start my_project
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

**www/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


    function deviceready()
    {
       var my_media = new Media('http://web.com/mp3');
       my_media.play();
       console.log(my_media.getDuration()); // this will produce -1
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got solution. 
I was using using old version of media plugin by default ( i think 2.0 ) 
I used removed old plugin with following command:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-media
```

Then I installed latest version of same plugin by using following command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media@2.2.0
```

And then I buit it again and it worked like charm.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to get getCurrentTime() but getDuration is still coming as -1 I am using ionic for building which using cordova. Any ideas how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ruta="/android_asset/www/sounds/M.mp3"; 
$scope.audiofile = new Media(ruta);
$scope.audiofile.play();

var timerDur = setInterval(function () {
    $scope.dur = $scope.audiofile.getDuration();
    if ($scope.dur > 0) {
        clearInterval(timerDur);
        console.log($scope.dur + " sec");
    }    
}, 1);
```

cordova plugin remove **cordova-plugin-media**

Then I installed latest version of same plugin by using following command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media@2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I always get -1 when trigger getDuration(). Here a solution reference, I found from [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-by-myself-handle-end-of-audio-file-event-ionic-native-media-on-android/108732/3)

```
getMediaDuration(path): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let audio: MediaObject = this.media.create(path);
      audio.seekTo(1);
      audio.onStatusUpdate.subscribe(status => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
          resolve(audio.getDuration());
          audio.release();
        }, 500);

      }); 
    });
  }
```

Tag: ionic 4, cordova-plugin-media, getDuration(), media.getDuration