# How to play multiple audio sequentially with ionic Media plugin

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-media-plugin

I am trying to play multiple audio files with ionic media plugin :  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media. but I am having a hard time making it work as a playlist without using a timeout function.

Here is what I have tried out

```
playOne(track: AudioFile): Promise<any> {


 return new Promise(async resolve =>{

      const AudFile =  await this.media.create(this.file.externalDataDirectory+track.trackUrl);


       await resolve(AudFile.play())

   });


  }
```

Then to play All , I have this :

```
async playAll(tracks: AudioFile[]): Promise<any>{
    let player = (acc, track:AudioFile) => acc.then(() => 

        this.playOne(track)


    );

   tracks.reduce(player, Promise.resolve());
  }
```

This way they are all playing at the same time.

But If  The PlayOne method is wrapped in a timeout function, the interval of the milli seconds set on the timeout exists among the play list, but one does not necessarily finish before the other starts and sometimes it waits for a long time before the subsequent file is plaid.

The timeout implementation looks like this :

```
playOne(track: AudioFile): Promise<any> {


 return new Promise(async resolve =>{
     setTimeout(async ()=>{
      const AudFile =  await this.media.create(this.file.externalDataDirectory+track.trackUrl);


       await resolve(AudFile.play())
     },3000)
   });


  }
```

Digging into ionic wrapper of the plugin, the create method  looks like this :

```
/**
 * Open a media file
 * @param src {string} A URI containing the audio content.
 * @return {MediaObject}
 */
Media.prototype.create = function (src) {
    var instance;
    if (checkAvailability(Media.getPluginRef(), null, Media.getPluginName()) ===
        true) {
        // Creates a new media object
        instance = new (Media.getPlugin())(src);
    }
    return new MediaObject(instance);
};
Media.pluginName = "Media";
Media.repo = "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media";
Media.plugin = "cordova-plugin-media";
Media.pluginRef = "Media";
Media.platforms = ["Android", "Browser", "iOS", "Windows"];
Media = __decorate([
    Injectable()
], Media);
return Media;
 }(IonicNativePlugin));
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Following the link to the plugin, I don't see any indication that `create` returns a promise, so it doesn't make sense to `await` it. Also, **never** pass an `async` function into `new Promise`, it doesn't make sense. Can you point to some documentation for that `create` function? The page you linked to links [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media), but that doesn't show a `create` function (which your code and the page you linked to use), it uses `Media` as a *constructor* (`new Media`), so...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your comments. I have edited my question to include the ionic create wrapper

Comment: Where is the API documentation for the plugin? The page you link to has usage examples, not API information as far as I can tell.

Comment: apart from the github link the other link I know of is https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got it to work with a recursive function. This works as expected.

```
PlayAllList(i,tracks: AudioFile[]){
    var self = this;

 this.Audiofile = this.media.create(this.file.externalDataDirectory+tracks[i].trackUrl);

 this.Audiofile.play()
   this.Audiofile.onSuccess.subscribe(() => {
    if ((i + 1) == tracks.length) {
      // do nothing
     } else {
       self.PlayAllList(i + 1, tracks)
     }



  })
}
```

Then

```
this.PlayAllList(0,tracks)
```

If there is any improvement on this, I will appreciate.

Comment: The problem there is: If you put a button there to stop the music, your code will play the next track, because onSuccess is trigger by stopping the track too.

Answer (score 4):

You may get it working by looping over your tracks and await `playOne` on each track.

```js
async playAll(tracks: AudioFile[]): Promise<any> {
  for (const track of tracks) {
    await this.playOne(track);
  }
}
```

If I'm not mistaking `play` function doesn't block until playing the audio file is finished. It doesn't return a promise either. A work around would be to use a seTimeout for the duration of the track

```js
playOne(track: AudioFile): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const audFile =  await this.media.create(this.file.externalDataDirectory+track.trackUrl);
    const duration = audFile.getDuration(); // duration in seconds

    AudFile.play();
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      },
      duration * 1000 // setTimeout expect milliseconds
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ismod, I tried setting the timeout to the duration of the track before, but I don't know why It's not able to get the duration of the track, so it returned -1. so no luck yet.

Comment: This is good logic. 
The only issue is that the duration() method initially returns -1 (it takes a while to read the metadata, and initially it is not set). However, there are workarounds to that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525276/cordova-media-getduration-returns-1/61358243#61358243

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be better of with the Web Audio API. I have used it before, and the possibilities are endless.

Apparently it can be used in Ionic without issues:
https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/using-web-audio-api-for-precision-audio-in-ionic

I have used it on http://chordoracle.com to play multiple audio samples at the same time (up to 6 simultaneous samples for each string of the guitar). In this case i also alter their pitch to get different notes.

In order to play multiple samples, you just need to create multiple bufferSources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createBufferSource

Some links to get you started:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/
- https://medium.com/better-programming/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-web-audio-api-3df170559378

Comment: I am using Ionic 4, not V1. Also, I found a plugin that works fine for the play list (Cordova Native Audio). but the challenge with that is it's able to play only the tracks shipped with the app. But I want to be able to download remote files and play them later.

Comment: I dont think your ionic version matters that much? The Web Audio API is widely supported ...